# how to make components visible in a transparent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, translucency

I have some JButtons in a JFrame (its layout is null). The background Color of the buttons are set Black. I have made the JFrame Transparent by using this code.

```
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0);
```

But the problem is it also makes all the buttons transparent as well. I don't want that. I want to see the buttons remaining black but the other portions of the JFrame becoming transparent (so that I can see the desktop background). Please someone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the call `button.setOpaque(true)` ?

Comment: it also does not work. buttons don't become visible with that.

Comment: Well I have found the solution for my problem.  Not, AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0);
I had to use instead:: 
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
And for every button and other components i had to call:
    button.setOpaque(true);
    label.setOpaque(true);
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, the problem was opacity set to zero. Any non-zero value with all button.setOpaque(true), will display buttons clearly. For me, AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame, 0.7f) works too.